# No module named Image windows ananconda

Tags: python, image, anaconda

```
 from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'D:\plate.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====output=======\n"
print text
```

it gets me error that

```
C:\Users\KEN\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/KENIL/PycharmProjects/plate/ocr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KEN/PycharmProjects/plate/ocr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
  File "C:\Users\KEN\PycharmProjects\plate\pytesser.py", line 6, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

even though i have installed ananconda properly as well as pillow [screenshot of package installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzAQU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't have the error. From the error message it seems that the error is in the module `pytesser.py`, where you probably use `Image` (in line 6 :-) ) without importing it.